# How to pass a variable from jQuery to Angular property

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a property inside an angular app called selected_tax, how can I pass a variable to this from jQuery?

I have a list of items that get filtered by their categories, I need a way to link to a pre-filtered list of category items. Currently, jQuery grabs a variable passed through the URL which is the category number.

Comment: why do you need jQuery to do this? Show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the scope from the "outside world". Just make sure you wrap the code inside a setTimeout to allow angular to do its magic and then invoke digest.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" id="myapp">{{xxx}}</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("app",[])
app.controller("ctrl",["$scope","$log",function($scope,$log){
  $scope.xxx = 'hello';
}])
</script>

<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#myapp").scope().xxx='gotcha!!! HAHA!';
    $("#myapp").scope().$digest();
  },0)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @simon, this passes to the 001 $rootScope, there is a nested 002 frontEnd scope also, it needs to be passed into that.

Comment: Bit hard to figure out without seeing your code. Can you post a bare bones version?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.property = $('#input_3').val();

$scope.input3val = window.property;
```

Comment: why do you need to pollute global namespace to do this?

Comment: if you use jquery with angular there is no way to pass 'variables' without polluting global namespace, or at least i don't know how

Comment: Please tell me how to do this without polluting global namespace or dom, i'm really interested. [i don't allow hidden inputs or other hacks like this as a response]

Comment: best way is run jQuery code inside a directive so you have scope access. Very hard to know what OP needs though without seeing any code

Comment: I approve with what u're saying, but he said "angular app ...  from jQuery". As i understand from this, he has 2 different scripts loaded.

Comment: no idea how you got that all figured out from a one sentence question and no code

Comment: I have a list of items that get filtered by their categories, I need a way to link to a pre-filtered list of category items. Currently, jQuery grabs a variable passed through the URL which is the category number.

Comment: Use jquery in a directive, don't use my approach for that.

Comment: You will have a key-value pair dictionary in $location.search(). [location provider -https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location]

Answer (score 0):

The method `$location.search()` will get you access to the query string of the url as a JSON object.  From the docs:

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

you can add $location to a controller through the dependencies

```
var app = angular.module("app",[])
app.controller("myController",["$scope, $location",function($scope, $location) {
   $scope.query = $location.search();
});
```

In your view template, you should then be able to use the query property to configure your jQuery calls.